# Temporarily disable magento extensions from the back end

Tags: magento

Is it possible to disable a Magento extension from the backend without uninstalling it or disabling it via the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Two important distinctions here**

**A)** Use **System > Configuration > Advanced** to shut off the module's output (module is still active)

**B)** To completely shut the module down and prevent execution of all its code, layouts, setups for both frontend and backend, go to **app/etc/modules/***, open the module control file of the desired module. Set the line **<active>true</active>** to read **false** in order to actually shut the module off.

The first is fine for taking care of display, the second is needed when an unruly module has knocked your Magento installation offline and you need instant removal of its activity.

And of course the usual Magento Mantra 1) make change, 2) clear Magento cache...

Comment: Thanks .... so no it isn't possible without going into the code then would be the answer then I take.

Comment: You do have to go into the control file in app/etc/modules/* to disable the module. I've had to do it for an over-the-weekend wait till a developer could help me get the module functional from a seeming bad install. Saves having to uninstall and find out you've messed that up as well, till you have the proper reversal procedure.